# *ngFor poor performance with large data

Tags: angular2-template, ngfor

I am having a data of 4000 records and listing with *ngfor in angular 2 but it terribly slow down my application performance. But if i use smaller data like 500 or 1000 it works better. Kindly suggest what should i do to cope with it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngx-virtual-scroll or ngx-infinite-scroll npm modules, when you have huge data.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-virtual-scroller

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-infinite-scroll